# How do I obtain more Golden Keys for Golden Chest(s)?

Tags: borderlands-2

I opened the Golden Chest in Sanctuary with the Golden Key I got with my pre-order bonus. I noticed that it ate my key, threw some loot at me, and then the chest didn't go away. I tried to open it again and it said I couldn't "afford" it and then displayed that I have no more Golden keys, which leads me to believe you can get more of them. If I can, how do I go about doing so?

Comment: Including his comment as he doesn't have enough rep, in case his answer is removed: @Lardofthedance pointed out that it may be a way of accessing DLC released later on. This would be markedly different to the way it worked in BL1, though.

Comment: The golden chest gives better loot the higher your player's level. If you had saved it until the end of the game it would have been much better.

Comment: I accidentally opened the chest. What a BAD MOVE! Man, I hate myself.

Comment: I, like many others, opened the chest not knowing wtf it was. More keys for when I'm max level would be awesome.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To get another Golden Key you can register at http://shift.gearboxsoftware.com and create a new character.  Then select your old character and enter the shift code you were emailed from linking your email and Steam account to SHiFT.

Also, be sure to follow Gearbox Software on [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/GearboxSoftware) and [Twitter](https://twitter.com/GearboxSoftware).  According to [Randy Pitchford](https://twitter.com/DuvalMagic), President of Gearbox, they plan on doing code SHiFT code giveaways to add more Golden Keys via these official sources in the future. ([source](https://twitter.com/DuvalMagic/status/251161349680422912)) They have several keys a week so far, usually a couple each day on Saturday/Sunday. They're still testing the concept according to Pitchford, so they may change how they do things.

As of October 2nd, 2012, Duval is still sending out SHiFT codes on his Twitter in an effort to test out the software that will eventually be used for the giveaways.  Since he is just testing the software, this could stop at anytime though.

Comment: According to [this source](http://www.gameranx.com/updates/id/9370/article/borderlans-2-how-to-get-golden-keys-veteran-skins/), this is legit.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I never received a shift code in my email.

Comment: Oh hey ! Shift... Gearbox... I see what they did there.

Comment: I don't get it either; is this something my character automatically gets for linking or is there a way to send the email? Like Nick I don't have a code, just a confirmation email which didn't have anything to input.

Comment: Are there any other ways to get Keys, or is this currently the only other known way? This definitely works (Confirming to also work when linking XBL acc with Shift), but I'm sure there is some way to get more?

Comment: Gonna give this answer for now, as this is the only confirmed legit way to currently get another key. Supposedly there will be more later, according to Gearbox.

Comment: will the code expire or be "claimed" as in there are only a number of quantity available to be redeemed.

Answer (score 11):

UPDATE: The developer has patched this so that this Golden Key hack does not work on the PC anymore. The console hack does still... so far.

If you're on the PC you can go to directory of the game then go to DLC, then premium club, then open the `WillowDLC.ini` with Notepad and edit it to:

```
[GoldenKeys]
+SourceId=254
+NumKeys=300

[PromotionalUnlocks]
+UnlockId=2
```

this will give you around 260 keys to use at your will

For Xbox 360 and PS3 watch this video for unlimited keys

Comment: They patched the game yesterday and it appears they've locked this down.  Editing the file doesn't seem to affect your key count anymore.

Comment: I still have my keys. I guess if you got it in early you're good.

Comment: Want to add that the amount of keys is stored in profile.bin. From my experience you can just backup it and put it back after you used your key and you will have another one

Comment: @SergeBekenkamp Correct. There are [profile.bin](http://www.mediafire.com/?q7cvqt9cicqthla) files available online that you can swap with your own in order to obtain more keys. Basically swap the downloaded profile with your original, get as many items as you want from the chest, then swap profiles back to your original. You will have the exact same save data but your inventory will still contain loot from the golden chest.

Comment: If you were to do a binary compare of the bin before and after using a key, you might find that the number of keys is stored in a specific place and may still be editable.

Comment: This answer would be better if it described the technique in the video.

Comment: It seems like the console 'hack' just gets you infinite level 7 loot, since you have to open the box with your fresh, level 1 character. Is that correct?

Answer (score 4):

On the PC version of Borderlands 2 your save data is broken into two parts: profile and character save.  The profile contains shared information between your characters such as bad-ass achievements, skin unlocks, and the golden keys.

Your character save contains weapon load-outs, current location, and class tree info.  Try deleting your profile and starting a new game with a new character.  This should give you a new key.  Then import your old character save into the new profile to access the key.  Note:  You will lose all information attached to your current profile if you delete it so back it up first.

This work around can also be used to unlock the chest as many times as you like.  Also, your save data should be located in: documents/mygames/borderlands2/willowgame/savedata for those who don't know.

Comment: This worked great, but seems to have the affect of resetting your bad-ass points, but the achievements are still unlocked. I assume this means that you will never be able to get those bad-ass points.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fix for those who didn't get emailed a shift code; go to shift.gearboxsoftware.com and **unlink** your Steam account. Then go into Borderlands' main menu, then Extra, then Shift. Sign in *here* and you should get your golden key without the passcode they don't seem to actually send out.