# What is the Golden Chest?

Tags: borderlands-2

I found a Golden Chest in Sanctuary. It says it costs one Golden Key to open it.

Should I open this chest? What's in it?

Comment: Made this because it's a *terribly* common problem that people waste their golden keys. It's a usability disaster.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This chest holds extremely good loot *for your level*. If you haven't opened the chest yet, **wait to open the chest for as long as possible**. If you open the chest at max level you'll get great purple or magenta (e-tech) rarity weapons. If you open it too early, you'll have a very good weapon for maybe 5-10 levels, and then it will be useless.

When playing co op with friends new to the game, make sure to warn them of the chest. It's an *extremely* common problem that people open the chest with no idea that it's special. It does finally have a warning that it will consume your keys when you try and open it now though.

You get the keys by activating your [preorder bonus](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/84665/how-do-i-get-my-preorder-bonuses) or by entering [Shift Codes](http://support.gearboxsoftware.com/forums/21326242-shift) from [GearboxSoftware](https://twitter.com/GearboxSoftware) and [Randy Pitchford](https://twitter.com/DuvalMagic) (President of Gearbox) on Twitter. The promotional [ECHOcasts account](https://twitter.com/ECHOcasts) also posts them less often than the other two. They occasionally tweet Shift Codes which can be entered in game to get keys. They release a couple a week or so. Note that Randy and Gearbox don't post the same shift codes (though the occasionally retweet eachother) so you should follow all 3 accounts if you want all of them. Be quick, shift codes expire either based on time or by how many people redeem them.

Comment: You also get a key by linking your Steam and Gearbox Shift accounts, as per [this answer to another question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/84721/6010)

Comment: Linking your Gearbox Shift account and Xbox gamer tag gets you a golden key, as well.

Answer (score 2):

I've opened the golden chest at least a hundred times (hacked key numbers to experiment), and every single item from it has been either purple or e-tech (red-purple).

No legendaries, ever.