# What do Golden Keys do, and how do they work?

Tags: borderlands-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the Golden Chest?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85067/what-is-the-golden-chest)

A pop-up says I have a golden key. Do they only work with the chest near the fast-travel station in Sanctuary?

What kinds of weapons/items does it spawn? Are they of a specific rarity set? What are the contents influenced by (e.g., level, game progress, other attributes)?

Answer (score 6):

The chest can spawn any kind of loot, it will be of purple (very rare) quality, and it will be scaled to the level of your character **at the moment you open the chest**, so if you want good end-game gear, save those keys!

Comment: Is it always purple, or does it have the chance of being orange quality too?