# Where is the most effective spot to item farm?

Tags: borderlands-2

Having beaten the main story quests of the game, I'm now running around mopping up side quests and preparing for a second playthrough of the game. I was curious where some of the best item farming places are in the game so I can deck out my character before starting playthrough 2.

Comment: You can farm the gold loot chest in the Sanctuary fast-travel room if this exploit still works for you (if you're on PC and haven't gotten the update, for example): http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/84699/how-do-i-obtain-more-golden-keys-for-golden-chests

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The best bosses to farm for items are BNK3R, Warrior and Terramorphous. You can't fast travel to these locations, so what you need to do is kill the boss, quit out of the game and then restart the game. The boss will be back and you'll be right at their front door instead of having to run the respective gauntlet before each boss.

Note that [Orange/legendary drops are extremely rare except from certain bosses](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85837/do-legendary-drops-only-come-from-specific-bosses) (even then orange drops are absurdly rare. Killed BNK3R 20 times this weekend and got squat). Farming is an effective way to get purple/blue weapons from any boss, but you'll need to target your farming if you want the legendaries.

Also note that Terra always spawns at level 52, so if you aren't level 50, don't bother. See also [my guide on killing the crap out of Terramorphous](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/86619/how-can-i-beat-terramorphous-the-invincible). Similar to the advice in that question, The Bee is an effective way to farm any boss; it used to be insanely easy, now it's just significantly helpful. The Bee has been nerfed (more specifically Amp Shields in general) so the boost is less significant for multi-projectile weapons, so if you're using the Bee, try a single bullet per shot, high rate of fire weapon like a Spinigun instead of a shotgun.

BNK3R in particular is easy to farm for Assassins since the Bore skill is bugged for him and sometimes he'll take repeated hits from it (with increasing damage) and die in very few  hits (or one).

However, regarding farming before playthrough 2...**Don't farm before playthrough 2**. Actually you need to be in playthrough 2.5 (e.g. complete playthrough 2) to get the best items possible. Don't farm until your level is maxed out; unlike Borderlands 1, damage follows an exponential scale in Borderlands 2. This means almost immediately after playthrough 1, orange level 30 guns are total crap compared to green level 35 guns. Ditto even up to level 45 guns. Everything is crap until you hit the level cap, just play normally until then and don't worry about farming.

Comment: I find that The Warrior only dropped legendaries the first time I killed him on any play-through with a character. Haven't tried the BNK3R yet though, since he's lower.

Comment: @Domenik that's because first time you kill warrior you have 75% chance to get an orange and then 5% after you kill him in playthrough and save.

Comment: As of the patch last week (12/11), the Bee has been nerfed to the point that Terramorphus cannot be easily killed with it equipped.

Comment: @aviangentile I meant to update my Terra guide based on that, forgot this answer referenced it. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 4):

In the wildlife exploitation center, if you haven't received the mission from Tannis, is the mission "Doctor's Orders". DO NOT collect any of the echo recordings. Instead fight your way to where the 2nd echo is (just after the super badass loader ambush) and in the room where the recording is there are 4 boxes. Opening each box without grabbing any echo recordings will almost always yield 4 loot midgets/loaders. Killing these at higher levels can yield aprrox. one legendary gun per 4 loot midgets/loaders. I myself after 4 runs on this location have received the corporate bitch, the impetuous hellfire, the vengeful ker blaster, and the 2 for 1 gunnerang. In my opinion it is the most effective farming method.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say my favorite looting spot is The Fridge. There are several bosses there, Laney at the beginning for the gub, then enter "the rats maze". At the othe end you can kill smash-head for Sledge's shotgun. Then follow the path until you find a elevator.
Go up to "the Rakcave" and and kill Rakkman for the gunerang. Then jump down, head back towards the beginning, but this time (from the start point) head right, go down stairs and Kill Shorty for the last orange gun. 4 legendaries here!

Answer (score 1):

Best way to get loot to me is to farm the Warrior a certain way. You and a buddy (you as the host) have the Final mission to "End This" and you head to heroes pass and kill Jack and Warrior. What you do is have your friend join with this active, kill Jack and Warrior and use lonar beacon bomb to blow the Warrior up. This gives a higher Orange loot drop rate than normal. It ONLY works with the mission active.

Any way, you kill the Warrior and Jack and if there is an orange weapon, have your buddy or whoever is not the host pick up and save and quit. Open your dashboard or find a way to quit without saving and then come back and do it again.  Note that you do not get Orange loot every time but I'd say you have at least a 7/10 chance of getting one every time you do this.

I later duplicated the loot I got and ended up with my friends having all the same orange loot. This included the Conference Call Slag, Shock, and Fire damage. The Sham shield. The Leech grenade mod fire. And the Volcano, all at level 50.

Answer (score 0):

The best farming you can do after finishing game is to kill warrior multiple times and hope for rare drops.

first you need to travel all the heroes pass again, once you are at warrior go and fight him, its you die you will re-spawn near save point don't jump down you can easily snipe him from the top of stairs without getting hit.

Once you killed it go loot all the stuff, don't leave the map save and quit and continue. you can fight warrior again as many times you want.

All the other places you wont get better loot, and soloing terramorphus in the first play-through is quiet impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I have found two orange weapons from trying to kill the black queen - I got them from killing the two men up by the church. There is a shortcut you can take up on the side of the hill, if you don't want to run all the way from the back of Ellie's. These two guys will start appearing after you complete the mission for Mordecai about the secret stash of weapons. The guys are extremely easy to kill if you have electric, fire, and corrosive weapons. The guy who kicks the church door open drops the veruc assault rifle, while the Hyperion agent can drop  the Lyudia/White death sniper rifle.

Answer (score 0):

I farmed both the Warrior and Bunker and they both have crap, IMHO that is, on my way to Terramorphus. I had better luck when I played Zero, now I'm playing Axton and have got nothing but crap the whole game. The only good thing is having two turrets

Answer (score 0):

i killed jack and the warrior in playthrough one. ( i'm level 35 right now)and when i went back to the red chest at the end of heroes pass (right before the vault of the warrior) i'm farming level 34 purple and e-tech gear there. also easily maxed out my 500 eridium.

i just run through heroes pass with my deception and toss a few homing grenades aheasd at key pointsgrenades and make it to the chest w/o having to fight anyone. then step into the vault, step back, save and you respawn right at the red chest with no enemies around.

but until i beat jack and the warrior, the chest was only giving level 30.

Answer (score -1):

i farm the super chests in opportunity.  there are 2 easy ones to get and once u learn the route to run its so quick and easy...I was averaging a e tech weapon every six boxes or so and purps and blues too...I do this at level 50 for max level gear drops....go and look up on youtube the video for farming the super chests in opportunity and you can learn the route

Comment: Rather than telling us to go look on youtube, how about you describe your route, and link to a video showing it?

Answer (score -2):

I farmed loot midgets near the second beacon for Doctor's Orders in the Wildlife Reserve.  Got at least 6 legendaries and one legendary grenade mod.  Without a doubt the best farming place with time and location taken into consideration.  Loot midgets are plentiful as long as Doctor's Orders is still active.  Do not pick up the second beacon, just raid the boxes, chests, and lockers, save / quit, rinse and repeat.

Comment: This is not easy to read. You might consider not typing with Caps Lock on.